# Spring transactional vs Hibernate session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, c3p0

I am using spring transactional and hibernate.

When i am calling to a flow which is using transactional, it seems that on a single flow 2 connections are being used!

It seems that hibernate is not using the same connection retrieved by Spring transactional.
So if i see how many connections are used in my pool i see as follows

- When service is being called there's no transaction, so a new transaction is being taken from the pool. (1 open transaction)
- When Dao is being called, nothing is being created, since we are in required propagational mode (still 1 open transaction)
- When criteria is being called, a new transaction is being created, so i see now 2 busy connections!

Am i missing something?

I know that's not common usage to have transactional in both layers (service and dao) but this is not my issue right now

Note that if in Dao i ask about session I do see that it is connected and it has a transaction (isConnected=true, getTransaction() has a

I am using spring and hibernate (v.4.1.7)
and I am using C3P0 Connection Provider
and underlying MySql database

Service

```
@Transactional
public StudentEntity getStudentById(String id) {
    StudentEntity entity = dao.getStudentById(id);
    return entity;
}
```

Dao

```
@Transactional
public StudentEntity getStudentById(String id) {
    //I have a sessionFactory provider - singleton
    Criteria criteria = this.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(StudentEntity.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(StudentEntity.MEMBER_ID, id));

    this.getCurrentSession().isConnected()//true !

    Object entity = criteria.uniqueResult();
    return (StudentEntity)entity;
}
```

Service Stack

```
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(long) BasicResourcePool.java:1414
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(long) BasicResourcePool.java:606
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(long) BasicResourcePool.java:526
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse() C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection() C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection() AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(Object, TransactionDefinition) DataSourceTransactionManager.java:204
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(TransactionDefinition) AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(PlatformTransactionManager, TransactionAttribute, String) TransactionAspectSupport.java:463
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(Method, Class, TransactionAspectSupport$InvocationCallback) TransactionAspectSupport.java:276
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) TransactionInterceptor.java:96
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.getStudent(String)
```

Dao Stack

```
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(long) BasicResourcePool.java:526
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse() C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection() C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection() AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection() AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140
org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection() InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70
com.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.MyMultiTenantConnectionProvider.getAnyConnection() MyMultiTenantConnectionProvider.java:43
com.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.MyMultiTenantConnectionProvider.getConnection(String) MyMultiTenantConnectionProvider.java:53
org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$ContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection() AbstractSessionImpl.java:344
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection() LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection() LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection() StatementPreparerImpl.java:56
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare() StatementPreparerImpl.java:159
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement() StatementPreparerImpl.java:183
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(String, boolean, ScrollMode) StatementPreparerImpl.java:157
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(String, QueryParameters, LimitHandler, boolean, SessionImplementor) Loader.java:1881
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(String, QueryParameters, boolean, List, SessionImplementor) Loader.java:1858
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(QueryParameters, boolean, List, SessionImplementor) Loader.java:1838
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, boolean, ResultTransformer) Loader.java:906
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, boolean, ResultTransformer) Loader.java:348
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, ResultTransformer) Loader.java:2550
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters) Loader.java:2536
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters) Loader.java:2366
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, Set, Type[]) Loader.java:2361
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(SessionImplementor) CriteriaLoader.java:124
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(Criteria) SessionImpl.java:1587
org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list() CriteriaImpl.java:374
org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult() CriteriaImpl.java:396
```

Comment: You are using the wrong transaction manager. You are using hibernate so you should be using the `HibernateTransactionManager`. Which also makes me wonder what your `getCurrentSession` actually does and what your hibernate configuration looks like.

Comment: Hi, I had a look to my configuration and i was wondering exactly about that, so after your comment i am more confident that this is the right solution. After changing to HibernateTransactionManager everything seems fine. Thanks!!!!!!